# exctract n rows every i rows

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, idl

I am quite new in the data analysis field.
I have a very big data file which contains millions of rows but repeated in the same patterns (100 steps time). I need to extract blocks formed by 100 rows every 10000 rows. In  this way I would discard same useless data.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this a reference to IDL (Interactive Data Language)? Are you asking for a solution within IDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '(NR-1)%10000<100'
```

Comment: Perfect! Very straightforward. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
awk 'NR % 10000 == 0 { line = 0 } line++ < 100' input.txt
```

will do the trick.